# What is wrong with these types?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyType.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    MyType myobject = MyType();
    std::cout << myobject; //error here
    return 0;
}
```

in `MyType.h`:

```
#include <ostream>

class MyType {
public:
    MyType();
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os);
};
```

in `MyType.cpp`:

```
#include "MyType.h"
#include <iostream>

MyType::MyType() {
}

std::ostream& MyType::operator<<(std::ostream &os){
    return os;
}
```

I am trying to overload << for a custom type. When I do, I get this error: `/main.cpp:14:15: Invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'MyType')`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you searched the FAQ?  Did you search StackOverflow for "c++ overloading <<"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You declare `operator<<` as a member function. So it only works if the invoking object is on its left hand side, as

```
MyType m;
m << (std::cout);
```

which looks like a monstrosity.

Best is to declare it as a friend,

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MyType& rhs)
{
   os << ...; // do something with rhs here
   return os;
}
```

then you can "naturally" invoke it

```
std::cout << myobject;
```

which is translated as

```
operator<<(std::cout, myobject);
```

StackOverflow has a very nice guide about [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/3093378) where you can find more details about operator overloading best practices.

---

**Unrelated**:

`MyType myobject = MyType();` is redundant and inefficient, as you are copy constructing the left hand side from a temporary `MyType()` that has to be also constructed (although the compiler usually optimizes this via copy elision). It is enough and more efficient to just write `MyType myobject`.